# Is it possible to access an android emulator on pc1 from pc2?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, android-emulator-plugin

Is it possible to access android emulator in pc1 from pc2?
We are trying to run android studio project and we need to access emulator that running in pc1 and all pc are connected in the same network.(Ubuntu)